# Remove everything after a particular substring using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, string

I thought this would have been simple, but after 3hrs of trying multiple different re.sub combinations, the answer is still eluding me.

I have the following string:

```
a = "99999 Anywhere Dr., Roanoak, VA 88888, ,"
```

I'd like to remove everything between the 88888 and the ending " (note there could be other characters other than space and comma, but there won't be another string of 5 digits after the 88888). I tried many combinations but the closest I got to what I was trying to accomplish was:

```
re.sub('(?=>\d{5})(.*)\".*$','',a)
```

This results in "99999" since it doesn't look from the end of the string but instead deletes everything after the first occurrence of the 5 digits. I want the result to be:

```
"99999 Anywhere Dr., Roanoak, VA 88888"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `re.sub`, I'd recommend `re.search` + *reassignment*:

```
m = re.search('.*\d{5}', text)
if m:
     text = m.group(0)

print(text)
'99999 Anywhere Dr., Roanoak, VA 88888'
```

```
.*        # greedy capture
\d{5}     # 5 digits
```

---

If you want to get inventive, you can *reverse* your string, and then call `re.sub`, so you look from the start.

```
text = re.sub('^.*?(?=\d{5})', '', text[::-1])[::-1]
print(text)
'99999 Anywhere Dr., Roanoak, VA 88888'
```

Reversing the string lets you use a lookahead now, which simplifies things.

```
^           # start of line
.*?         # non-greedy capture
(?=         # lookahead 
\d{5}       # 5 digits
)
```

Comment: The greedy capture worked! Thx. So "greedy" means just keep looking through the string until you find the last occurrence of the regex? If that's what it is then i leaned something today :)!

Comment: LOL! Done. Thanks again!

Comment: Who would have thought about string reversion! To extract the body from a piece of html, I did this: `r1, r2 = '^.*<body>', '^.*>ydob/<'` and `re.sub(r2, '', re.sub(r1, '', html, flags=re.DOTALL)[::-1], flags=re.DOTALL)[::-1]`.  Made my day.

Comment: @PatrickT if parsing html I'd always recommend a parser over regex, it's a glaring antipattern and has low success rates.

Comment: @cs95, Sadly success rates are person-dependent: I went with regex after giving up on parsing. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using re.match:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "99999 Anywhere Dr., Roanoak, VA 88888, ,"
>>> re.match(r'^.*[\d{5}]?\d{5}', a).group(0)
'99999 Anywhere Dr., Roanoak, VA 88888'
```

or re.search:

```
>>> re.search(r'^.*[\d{5}]?\d{5}', a).group(0)
'99999 Anywhere Dr., Roanoak, VA 88888'
```

Comment: Do you know what `[\d{5}]` is doing? Definitely not what you think.

Comment: I use this to "catch" the last occurrence of the 5 digits,  I think : )

Comment: Well, it doesn't do that. Your pattern works, but your understanding of what it does is incorrect. Anything within a character class is just that - a group of characters.